# dynamic css grid layout, keeping some elements on the same line

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I have started using css grids recently (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) but feel like I'm not fully exploiting them. My question concerns a situation where my displayed data is dynamic. For instance I want to display this:

[image: display layout]

In short:

- each row of data can contain one or two columns
- rows are separated by a divider row
- data is dynamic, the css grid layout cannot be pre-set

It feels like css grids have a way of doing this (without dynamically generating the css), using repeat etc... but I don't really see how.
This is done under React, some dynamic rows are generated using a map, the code would looks something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <div> 1A </div>
    <div> 1B </div>
    <MyDivider />

    <div> 2 </div>
    <MyDivider />

    {myData.map((row) => (
      <div key={row.key}>
        <div>{row.A}</div>
        <div>{row.B}</div>
        <MyDivider />
      </div>
    ))}

    // more rows, with single (merged) or dual columns...
  </div>
);
```

Is it possible to do this without dynamically generating the grid css? Namely, defining grid settings for single / dual column lines, and divider lines? Also, due to the map function, under React, my dynamic content ends up wrapped in a div; do I need to break this down in multiple map's so that I don't have this wrapping div?

Thanks!

---

**Edit 10/24/2020:**
To clarify things, I don't want to literally display what is in this drawing, this is just a layout, with each '1A', '1B' block corresponding to some data cell, just like in a tabulator.

Comment: Are you able to modify the component to add classes to the elements to show wher they should span both columns or a single column?

Comment: Yes definitely, that's my intent, I am just not sure how to map that in the grid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know if a row is single or dual columns.
You can make a cell span by using `grid-column` like the sample below

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 5px; // for demonstration purposes
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue; // for demonstration purposes
}

.grid-item.single {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-separator {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: lightgreen; // for demonstration purposes
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">A1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">B1</div>
  <div class="grid-separator">Separator</div>
  <div class="grid-item single">A2</div>
  <div class="grid-separator">Separator</div>
  <div class="grid-item">A3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">B3</div>
  <div class="grid-separator">Separator</div>
  <div class="grid-item">A4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">B4</div>
  <div class="grid-separator">Separator</div>
  <div class="grid-item single">A5</div>
</div>
```

Note that you need to add the `single` class under some condition

Comment: Great, I was missing the span control. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your css or you can do it like that way...

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid div  {
text-align: center;
background: #ddd;
margin: 2px;
padding: 10px;
}
.mydevider {
grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" >
  <div> 1A </div>
  <div> 1B </div>
  <div class="mydevider">
    <div> 1A </div>
  </div>
  <div> 1B </div>
  <div> 1B </div>
  <div class="mydevider">
    <div> 1A </div>
  </div>
  <div> 1B </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. However I am not trying to display elements in a column, I am aiming for what is illustrated in the drawing (where elements can either be grouped on the same row, or alone). Also concerning the divider, it is a custom React component, I'm not trying to use the grid's borders.